# Javascript (jQuery) if statement rewrite

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing some JavaScript (with jQuery) that needs to be more flexible. However, I'm not sure how to approach this. This is my code:

```
var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
var scrollArr = $('.data').html().split(",");  // eg. array is 0,80,240,350,380,630

function doIt() {
    if (scrollTop<parseInt(scrollArr[0])) {
        //$('.scrollShow img').eq(0).removeClass('h')
    }
    if (scrollTop>parseInt(scrollArr[0])&&scrollTop<parseInt(scrollArr[1])) {
        $('.scrollShow .anim').eq(0).addClass('o01s')
    }
    if (scrollTop>parseInt(scrollArr[1])&&scrollTop<parseInt(scrollArr[2])) {
        $('.scrollShow .anim').eq(1).addClass('o01s')
    }         
    if (scrollTop>parseInt(scrollArr[2])&&scrollTop<parseInt(scrollArr[3])) {
        $('.scrollShow .anim').eq(2).addClass('o01s')
    }
}
```

The problem is that the amount of elements in the array (scrollArr) will vary each time the doIt() function is run, so if/else statements are not practical in my opinion. What should I replace them with? The code to be executed would be the same (as the above example - with the number increment) and so a flexible function seems more appropriate. Or am I going about this the wrong way? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: [Use a `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to iterate through the entire array.

Comment: How? I don't know what scrollTop is going to be.

Comment: in each iteration of the loop, just compare scrollTop to scrollArr[i], if scrollTop is less than scrollArr[i], then do eq(i-1). Be careful of edge cases though (particularly when i=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<scrollArr.length; i++) {
    if(scrollTop>parseInt(scrollArr[i])&&scrollTop<parseInt(scrollArr[i+1]))
    {
        $('.scrollShow .anim').eq(i).addClass('o01s')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that was embarrassingly obvious!